# Set a class static

Tags: c++, class, templates, variable-declaration

I'm trying to write a class as an exercise and have the following:

```
template <class Foo>
class Bar
{
protected:
    Foo _x,_y,_z;
public:
    Bar(Foo x, Foo y, Foo z) {_x=x; _y=y; _z=z;};
    Bar() {_x=0; _y=0; _z=0;};

    static const Bar<Foo> X;
};
```

I'll like to initialise `X` as `(0,1,0)` but have no idea how to do so. I would like declare `X =(0,1,0)` to be like declaring `#define pi = 3.142` at the start of a program. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have C++11 available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is fine, but you're probably getting a linker error as you're not providing any storage for `X`. You need to do this:

```
template <class Foo>
class Bar
{
protected:
    Foo _x,_y,_z;
public:
    Bar(Foo x, Foo y, Foo z) {_x=x; _y=y; _z=z;};
    Bar() {_x=0; _y=0; _z=0;};

    static const Bar<Foo> X;
};

template <typename Foo>
const Bar<Foo> Bar<Foo>::X(0, 1, 0);
```

Unlike non-template static variables, this is fine to go in a header -- as with other templates, duplicate definitions of `Bar<Foo>::X` will be merged at link-time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the static declaration from the class:

```
template <class Foo>
class Bar
{
protected:
    Foo _x,_y,_z;
public:
    Bar(Foo x, Foo y, Foo z) {_x=x; _y=y; _z=z;};
    Bar() {_x=0; _y=0; _z=0;};
};


const Bar<Foo> X(0,1,0); // Foo should be a type...
```

Comment: But `Foo` is not declared outside of the class, so how do I remedy that?

Comment: Foo is just a template-type for something you have to specify somewhere. Foo also isn't really declared in the class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the reason why I'm using class template is because I don't want to tie myself down to just `int` for `Foo`,  I may want to use `double`,`long` for example, so that was why I'm hoping to stick with `Foo`.

Comment: @BlackAdder ok i understand that :) , but than you should know that you always have to specify the type while using the constant.